# Post request error in Api Fetch with asp.net C #

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am making a post request with api fetch, at the moment I reach the breakpoint the parameters arrive or inform me that they are null, therefore this part generates an error, I have already verified the variables to which it assigns the html objects , the variables you sent are user identification, start date and end date, this data was sent to an object that requires the C # method, so it makes a query with the information that I require, which I want to know why when doing this method it arrives null data to the backend, annex code and running image

View

```
@using System.Globalization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Reporte Rh";
}
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <!-- Default box -->
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title text-primary"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> @ViewData["Title"]</h3>
                <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip"
                            title="Collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div id="Grid">


                    <form role="form" method="post">

                        <div class="form-group has-success">
                            <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>@Localizer["Cedula"]</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" placeholder="Enter ...">
                        </div>
                        <label for="start" class="control-label">Start date:</label>

                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start" name="trip-start"
                               value="2018-07-22"
                               min="2018-01-01" max="3000-12-31">

                        <label for="start" class="control-label">And date:</label>

                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="end" name="trip-start"
                               value="2018-07-22"
                               min="2018-01-01" max="3000-12-31">
                        <!-- /.col Botom-->
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="ValidarExisteContacto()">@Localizer["Reporte"]</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer">

            </div>
            <!-- /.box-footer-->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
<script src="~/Scripts/ReporteRh/ValidacionReporteReporteRh.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
function ValidarExisteContacto() {
    var existeUsuario;   
    if ($("#cedula").val() !== null || $("#start").val() !== null || $("#end").val() !== null) {
        //const url = '/ReporteRh/CreatePdfs';
        var url = '/ReporteRh/CreatePdfs';
        var cedula = $("#cedula").val();
        var start = $("#start").val();
        var end = $("#end").val();
        const myPost = {
            cedula: cedula,
            start: start,
            end: end
        };

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(myPost)
        }).then((res) => {
            if (res.ok) {
                existeUsuario = true;
                console.log(res);
                return res.json();
            } else {
                existeUsuario = false;
                console.log(res);
                return Promise.reject({ status: res.status, statusText: res.statusText });
            }

        })
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error message:', err.statusText) );


    } 

    return existeUsuario;
}
```

```
/// <summary>
        /// Metodo para el reporte
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost]
        public FileResult CreatePdfs(ReporteLabViewModels model)
        {
            //ReporteLabViewModels model = new ReporteLabViewModels();
            MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
            StringBuilder status = new StringBuilder("");
            DateTime dTime = DateTime.Now;
            //Crea archivo con nombre 
            string strPDFFileName = string.Format("SamplePdf" + dTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "-" + ".pdf");

            if (model.cedula != null)
            {
                var sql = from d in demoDrHelpContext.DatosPacientes
                          join rh in demoDrHelpContext.Rh on d.Id equals rh.IdPaciente
                          join gr in demoDrHelpContext.GrupoSanguineo on rh.IdGrupoSanguineo equals gr.Id
                          join nt in demoDrHelpContext.NotificacionExamen on d.Id equals nt.IdPaciente
                          where nt.FechaRegistro >= model.start && nt.FechaRegistro <= model.end && d.Codigo == model.cedula
                          select new { d.Nombre, d.Codigo, d.Edad, gr.Sigla, nt.FechaRealizada };




                if (sql == null)
                {
                    foreach (var grouprh in sql)
                    {
                        #region Area del reporte pdf

                        iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                        doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

                        //Crea PDF Table con 5 columnas
                        PdfPTable tableLayout = new PdfPTable(5);
                        doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
                        //Create PDF Table

                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;

                        doc.Open();
                        // Crear un ImageData object       
                        //Agrega la tabla del pdf 

                        string imageURL = "C:/Apoyo Mederic/archive/APOYO MEDERI-1.png";

                        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);
                        iTextSharp.text.Image jpgs = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);

                        //Cambiar el tamaño de la imagen depende de su necesidad
                        jpg.ScaleToFit(120f, 100f);

                        //Dar espacio antes de la imagen

                        jpg.SpacingBefore = 10f;

                        //Dar algo de espacio después de la imagen.

                        jpg.SpacingAfter = 1f;

                        jpg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                        // Escribimos el encabezamiento en el documento

                        Font fonts = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, Font.BOLD);
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph(dTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), fonts));
                        doc.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

                        // Este codigo genera una tabla de 3 columnas
                        PdfPTable tablets = new PdfPTable(2);
                        tablets.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                        Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLD);
                        Paragraph pLong = new Paragraph("LABORATORIO CLINICO", font);
                        pLong.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                        doc.Add(pLong);

                        // Creando una tabla     
                        float[] pointColumnWidths = { 150F, 150F };
                        PdfPTable tablew = new PdfPTable(pointColumnWidths);

                        // Adding cells to the table   
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT }); tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                             new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });
                        // Adding cells to the table   
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT }); tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                             new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(jpg);

                        // Agregar celdas a la tabla 
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT }); tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                             new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });
                        // Adding cells to the table   
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Numero Documeno ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                                           new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });


                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Nombre ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                           new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                                   new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Fecha ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                          new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(grouprh.FechaRealizada.ToString(), new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                                   new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });


                        //tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Activo ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                        //   new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        //{ Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        //tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(genero.Activo.ToString(), new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                        //    new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        //{ Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        // Agregar celdas a la tabla 
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT }); tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                             new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });


                        // Agregar celdas a la tabla  
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT }); tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                             new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });



                        // Agregar tabla al documento
                        doc.Add(tablew);

                        doc.Add(tablets);

                        doc.Add(Add_Content_To_PDFS(tableLayout, model));

                        // Cierra el documento
                        doc.Close();

                        #endregion

                    }


                }
                else
                {

                    foreach (var grouprh in sql)
                    {

                        #region Area del reporte pdf

                        iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                        doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

                        //Crea PDF Table con 5 columnas
                        PdfPTable tableLayout = new PdfPTable(5);
                        doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
                        //Create PDF Table

                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;

                        doc.Open();
                        // Crear un ImageData object       
                        //Agrega la tabla del pdf 

                        string imageURL = "C:/Apoyo Mederic/archive/APOYO MEDERI-1.png";

                        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);
                        iTextSharp.text.Image jpgs = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);

                        //Cambiar el tamaño de la imagen depende de su necesidad
                        jpg.ScaleToFit(120f, 100f);

                        //Dar espacio antes de la imagen

                        jpg.SpacingBefore = 10f;

                        //Dar algo de espacio después de la imagen.

                        jpg.SpacingAfter = 1f;

                        jpg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                        // Escribimos el encabezamiento en el documento

                        Font fonts = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, Font.BOLD);
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph(dTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), fonts));
                        doc.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

                        // Este codigo genera una tabla de 3 columnas
                        PdfPTable tablets = new PdfPTable(2);
                        tablets.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                        Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLD);
                        Paragraph pLong = new Paragraph("LABORATORIO CLINICO", font);
                        pLong.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                        doc.Add(pLong);

                        // Creando una tabla     
                        float[] pointColumnWidths = { 150F, 150F };
                        PdfPTable tablew = new PdfPTable(pointColumnWidths);

                        // Adding cells to the table   
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT }); tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                             new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });
                        // Adding cells to the table   
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT }); tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                             new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(jpg);

                        // Agregar celdas a la tabla 
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT }); tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                             new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });
                        // Adding cells to the table   
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Codigo ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });


                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(grouprh.Codigo.ToString(), new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Nombre ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                           new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(grouprh.Nombre.ToString(), new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Activo ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                           new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(grouprh.FechaRealizada.ToString(), new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });

                        // Agregar celdas a la tabla 
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT }); tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                             new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });


                        // Agregar celdas a la tabla  
                        tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                            new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT }); tablew.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1,
                             new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
                        { Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 5, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT });



                        // Agregar tabla al documento
                        doc.Add(tablew);

                        doc.Add(tablets);

                        GrupoSanguineoViewModels rhViewmModels = new GrupoSanguineoViewModels
                        {
                            Sigla = grouprh.Sigla
                        };
                        doc.Add(Add_Content_To_PDF(tableLayout, rhViewmModels));

                        // Cierra el documento
                        doc.Close();

                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            }



            byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
            workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
            workStream.Position = 0;


            return File(workStream, "application/pdf", strPDFFileName);


        }
```

Demonstration from the browser side

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide json data also which you are trying to send to server?

Comment: Hi  is the response to the server, but the method does not reach the backend

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem the object could link the name of the objects of the text

```
function ValidarExisteContacto() {
var existeUsuario;   
if ($("#cedula").val() !== null || $("#start").val() !== null || $("#end").val() !== null) {


    const myPost = {
        cedula: $("#cedula").val(),
        start: $("#start").val(),
        end: $("#end").val()
    };

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(myPost)
    }).then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
            existeUsuario = true;
            console.log(res);
            return res.json();
        } else {
            existeUsuario = false;
            console.log(res);
            return Promise.reject({ status: res.status, statusText: res.statusText });
        }

    })
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log('Error message:', err.statusText) );


} 

return existeUsuario;
```

}